# Recommend me a text or webpage introducting gamma function throughly

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, gamma-function

Till now, i have learned abstract Integration, all basic properties of the (n-dimensional) Lebesgue(-Stieltjes) measure and the lebesgue integral is an extension of Riemann integral.

Here's an illustration i'm curious about:

Let $\Gamma$ be a complex-valued gamma function.

Often, it's written in texts $\Gamma(z)=\int_{0}^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt$. ($Re(z)>0$)

If i understand this integral as the Lebesgue-integral, it makes sense to me. However if this integral is the Riemann-integral, i wonder which limit should be taken first. That is, is it taking limit first to $0$ and then to $\infty$? Or first to $\infty$ then to $0$? Or an order of taking limit doesn't matter? What are relations between the Lebesgue integral and Riemann *improper* integral?

Please suggest me a text which could answer these questions. However, i don't want to spend *very much* time on this. I hope i can learn these topics within 2 or 3 days. Thank you :)

Comment: Three mainstream real-analysis texts don't introduce relations between improper riemann and lebesgue. (Rudin,Royden,Folland)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps "The Gamma Function" by Emil Artin, very short, and in pdf format, ( just google it.)

Otherwise just about any book on the theory of functions such as Ahlfors' Complex Analysis. I'm guessing this list is fairly long.

Answer (score 1):

I learned all I know (well maybe not all, but quite a bit) about the gamma function from Frank Jones' *Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Spaces*. Chapter 11 I want to say. I feel that the text introduces the concepts in a relatively straight forward manner accessible by an upper division undergrad, beginning grad student.

Jones also addresses topics on Lebesgue versus Riemann integration.

Comment: Ch11 is not about Gamma function?@vladhagen

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a good reference for the gamma function (maybe Abramowitz and Stegun?) but I can answer your integration question.  In general there are improper Riemann integrals that are not Lebesgue integrals, and vice versa.  (Wikipedia has an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals) of an improper Riemann integral that is not Lesbegue.

In this particular case, where the integrand is positive, they coincide.  You can prove that via the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).